# Gestures using c# in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to use gestures in an application like those described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj883700.aspx).

Can any one provide a good tutorial or explanation where I learn the basics.

Thanks.

Comment: Your link has examples including code, is there something else you need from it? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59

Comment: Yes pinch,stretch and rotate to make control size greater,lower and rotation of it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Pan / zoom into an image? Stackoverflow works best when questions are specific.

Comment: I want to apply pinch stretch and rotate gesture to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the links in the comments they show you how to pan / zoom. Zooming is generally done with the ScrollViewer as in the example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ScrollViewer-pan-and-949d29e9/sourcecode?fileId=50991&pathId=592740750).

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="480" Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.7"> 
    <StackPanel Width="480" Height="270" Orientation="Horizontal"> 
      <Image AutomationProperties.Name="Image of a cliff" Source="images/cliff.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

The `ScrollViewer` handles pinch + zoom for you.

Rotation you'd have to handle yourself though [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59/sourcecode?fileId=98906&pathId=110278734) should show you how.

In this case you set up a `GestureRecognizer` to include `Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotate` and wire up to the `ManipulationUpdated` event.

In that link it shows you that you can get the difference between manipulations (the delta Transform) via the `ManupulationUpdatedEventArgs` `.Delta.Rotation` property.

Once you have that value you can do whatever you need to with it.
For example if you have a named image with a Transform i.e in your XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding YourImageUrl}" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="myTransform" Rotation="0"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Then you could in response to the manipulation delta you could set `myTransform.Rotation = myTransform.Rotation + Delta.Rotation`.

You may get into a pickle with mixing the built in behaviour of the `ScrollViewer` and manual handling of the manipulation events, which might mean you need to handle it all yourself via the Manipulation events.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if we have an image that is dynamically generated it doesnot have scrollviewer as define above ?

Comment: I'm using ScrollViewer in that example because it makes Pinch to Zoom really easy, if you're not going to alter the size of the image (as you would in a zoom) then you don't need the ScrollViewer.